# Equation of a sphere passing 3 points and tangential to a line

Tags: spherical-geometry

I got a maths question that gives you 3 points, $A (6,0,0)$ and $B (6,6,0)$ and $C (0,6,0)$ and a line DG, D being $(0,0,6)$ and $G (0,6,6)$ so the equation of DG is $\vec r$ = 6$\hat i$ -$6t\hat j$ . You're then asked to find the equation of the sphere that contains those 3 points and is tangential to the line.

I know that if I had 4 points I could do a simultaneous equation(s), but I don't see how that could work here. Please help.

I should maybe mention that the $origin, A, B, C, D, G, E(6,0,6) ~and~ F (6,6,6)$ form the 3 corners of a cube.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sphere can be represented as
$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2=r^2$$
where the center is $(a,b,c)$ and its radius is $r$.

Setting each of $(x,y,z)=(6,0,0),(6,6,0),(0,6,0)$ in the equation, you'll get
$$(6-a)^2+(0-b)^2+(0-c)^2=r^2,$$
$$(6-a)^2+(6-b)^2+(0-c)^2=r^.2$$
$$(0-a)^2+(6-b)^2+(0-c)^2=r^2.$$

Hence, you'll get
$$(a,b,c)=(3,3,r^2-18).$$

Now we know that the equation of the sphere is represented as
$$(x-3)^2+(y-3)^2+(z-r^2+18)^2=r^2.$$

Then, you can set 
$$(x,y,z)=(0, 6t, 6)$$
in the equation (because the line $DG$ is represented as $(0,0,6)+t(0,6,0)$.)

Then, you'll have an equation with $t,r$, so what you do is to find $r$ such that the equation has only one real solution $t$.

Comment: One can also use the fact that the distance of the co-ordinate of the center of the sphere from the tangent line has to be equal to r.

Comment: "Setting three points in the equation, you'll get
(a,b,c)=(3,3,r2−18).
Now we know that the equation of the sphere is represented as
(x−3)2+(y−3)2+(z−r2+18)2=r2."



Wait, how did you get the coordinates of the centre of the sphere?

Comment: @Sebastian: I added a bit. see my answer.